# NSStream not giving any data

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, stream, telnet

I'm trying to write telnet client on iOS and I can't set up streams correctly. I think that they work, but I am getting empty buffer each time I get delegate method triggered.

Here is how I set up streams:

```
self.manager = [[TelnetManager alloc] init];

CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)[[NSURL URLWithString:@"arda.pp.ru"] host], 7000, &readStream, &writeStream);

NSInputStream *inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self.manager];
[outputStream setDelegate:self.manager];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
```

Here is the delegate method that is on manager that handles events:

```
-(void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{
    if (eventCode == NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable) {
        NSLog(@"We got some data over here");
            if(!_data) {
                _data = [NSMutableData data];
            }
            uint8_t buf[1024];
            unsigned int len = 0;
            len = [(NSInputStream *)aStream read:buf maxLength:1024];
        NSLog(@"length - %d", len);
        NSLog(@"buf:%s", buf);
            if(len) {
                [_data appendBytes:(const void *)buf length:len];
                _bytesRead = @([_bytesRead intValue]+len);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"no buffer!");
            }
    }
}
```

It is getting fired, but buffer is always empty and "no buffer" is logged.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You might want to look into https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket. It makes working with sockets bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually is nothing wrong with your code. I have used it to connect to a telnet server and it worked fine.

In your code, "no buffer" is logged when `len` is 0, which means the buffer's end has been reached. In the case of a telnet server, this usually means that either the server disconnected your connection or the server quit.